# constrained convex optimisation for a multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, optimization

Given some multivariate normal distribution $P(\mathbf{x|\mu,\Sigma} )$ I'm looking for a method to maximise $P$ subject to $x_i \ge 0 \; \forall \; i$.

I guess this is typically approached by instead minimising

$f(\mathbf{x}) = (\mathbf{x - \mu})^{\top}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x - \mu}) $

subject to our constraints on $\mathbf{x}$.

**Can anyone suggest an algorithm for solving the problem?**

I'm happy to implement it myself, since I need it to be in Python and use the scipy.sparse matrix formats (as $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is large and sparse).

Thanks!

Comment: What parts of this problem are known and what parts are estimated? A normal distribution has support over all real numbers, so in the case that $x$ is known, the non-negativity constraint is irrelevant. However, if you want to assign 0 probability to $x < 0$, then this isn't a normal distribution, so the normal model is inappropriate. If you're doing MLE for $\mu, \Sigma$, then you just write the likelihood and optimize, but you end up with the well-known result that sample mean and sample covariance maximize this likelihood.

Comment: @Sycorax $\mu, \Sigma$ are known in this case. It's for a problem in physics data analysis where we have a linear model, errors that can reasonably be approximated as normal, which gives a multivariate normal likelihood. There's also a normal prior distribution involved, so we end up with a multivariate normal posterior, but the argument is a physical quantity that must be non-negative. The assumption we're making currently is that it's easier to keep everything normal and then solve the problem with constraints rather than solve a much harder problem without constraints.

Comment: This is classical [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming), for which a lot of theory exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The optimization problem$$\min_x (x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)$$

subject to $x \geq 0$ falls under a class of problem known as [quadratic programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use lognormals instead of normals if you want to force x>0? Then you can just solve it with maximum likelihood estimation.

Numerically, the python package CVXOPT should be able to do this and supports sparse matrices. You can figure out how to change matrix to sparse matrix in a way that suits your problem here:
http://cvxopt.org/userguide/matrices.html

Example code for dense matrices:

```
def opt(mu, cov):
    """
    minimize    (x -mu )' Q (x - mu)
    subject to  x > 0
    where Q is the precision matrix cov^(-1)

    CVXOPT minimizes    x'Px + q'x·
    subject to          Gx <= h
                        Ax == b

    The objective can be rewritten as x'Qx - 2 mu' Q x
    since mu' Q mu is a constant.

    So gathering up the terms we have that P = Q,·
    q' = -2 mu' Q, G = -1, A = 0, b = 0 and h = 0

    mu: means of shape n_samples
    cov: covariance matrix of shape (n_features, n_features)

    """

    n_features = cov.shape[0]
    Q = np.linalg.inv(cov)

    # objective
    P = matrix(Q)
    q = matrix((-2*mu[None, :].dot(Q)).T)

    # constraints

    G = matrix(-np.identity(n_features))
    A = matrix(0.0, (n_features, n_features))
    b = matrix(0.0, (n_features, 1))
    h = matrix(0.0, (n_features, 1))

    sol = solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)
    return np.asarray(sol['x']).ravel()
```

However this gives rank errors for some reason, meaning that something with the problem is ill defined (or that I made some error). Hope it helps at least.

Comment: You seem to confuse a lognormal *distribution* with the *logarithm of the density* of a normal distribution.  They are quite different things!

Comment: @whuber I understand the difference. The means and variances come from somewhere though and I don't understand why the data wasn't transformed to the log scale before estimating the means and covariance. Without the x > 0 constraint, the answer would just be $x = \mu$

Comment: I wonder how you are interpreting the question.  It is confusing; but as I read it, it has nothing whatsoever to do with distributions, Normal or otherwise.  It merely asks how to optimize the exponential of a quadratic form subject to linear (inequality) constraints.  Of course that's equivalent to optimizing the form itself, as the last part of the question points out.